# Retreiving ship-to-party country SAP QuickViewer

Tags: sap-erp, sap-query

I've created a QuickView, where I enter Sales Document data as search criteria.

Selection fields are

```
VBAP-VBELN, VBAP-POSNR, VBAP-MATNR and VBAP-KWMENG
```

As the Sales Document Item data.

Furthermore I retrieve the Schedule line date from

```
VBEP-EDATU
```

From General Data in Customer Header KNA1, I use

```
KNA1-KUNNR and KNA1-LAND1
```

Now, all connections and keys works out. My issue is, I wish to list the Country Key for **ship-to-part** rather than **sold-to-party** (which is represented by KUNNR). How could this be solved?

Tables are joined as follows:

```
VBAK-VBELN -> (VBAP-VBELN,-POSNR) -> (VBEP-VBELN, -POSNR)
VBAK-KUNNR -> KNA1-KUNNR
```

I do know I would probably need a new table in here to retrieve what I'm looking for, but I'm completely blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: I need to create the report entirely in QuickViewer with ABAP tables/dict. I could use layouts with filters for the final report.

Comment: I've managed to fetch the country for ship-to-party, using LIPS-VBELN to connect to LIKP-VBELN, and setting LIKP-KUNNR = KNA1-KUNNR. However, now the issue is different: I get the correct data as sought after, but now it only fetches the data when a production order has been created. DOes it have anything to do with VBEP-EDATU options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ship-To-Party is stored in table VPBA (Sales Document Partners) in field KUNNR1 for partner function SH, so to select it you should join KNA1 not with VBAK but with VBPA-KUNNR restricting function to SH.

However, SQVI is a very primitive tool which doesn't allow setting complex (neither trivial) conditions so you should switch to ABAP queries tool (SQ01).

But just in case you wanna do this in SQVI here is the workaround:

1. Join necessary tables in SQVI builder

[image]

2. Add necessary KNA1 fields to layout: KUNNR and LANDX
3. Go to layout mode and enable selection by partner function PARVW

[image]

4. Run your query by SH partner function

[image]

5. and voilá! You will be shown only the orders with ship-to-party specified with their countries

[image]

Comment: Amazing - worked like a charm! Thanks for the tips as to switching to ABAP, I will get into it! :-)